# Can Socket.Receive() return 0 if the connection is still open?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming

I am writing a C# .NET server application that sends and receives data over Sockets, and I am having some issues if the client application crashes without closing the socket the right way.

I have set the 'receive timeout' to a given value, and I expected the Socket.Receive() to throw an exception after that amount of time. But instead the method just returns 0.

So my question is: Is it possible that the socket is still open if the `Socket.Receive()` returns 0? Or can I safely assume that it is down?

(Might be a bit tricky to understand. If so, please let me know in the comments)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope. It's down if you receive 0.

From MSDN:

> If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response!
I read that article, but I couldn't figure out if that is the only case when the method can return 0. But you are sure of this?

Comment: @csharptest.net this is also my experience. but do you have any reference for this (official documentation)?

Comment: @RobertHegner: It's the way that sockets work. 0 can only be received if the socket is down. Isn't the MSDN article that I linked to official enough? Here is the one for the C method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hm… I am receiving zero, but the property `mySocket.Connected` still returns true; I'm wondering what could that mean.

Comment: That `Connected` is unreliable. I don't think it changes unless something is sent. From MSDN: *If you need to determine the current state of the connection, make a nonblocking, zero-byte Send call*

Comment: Okay, I don't know what was the problem, but I fixed it by adding a line like `if (sock.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && sock.Available == 0) { /* connection closed */ }` — be sure, the code inside of braces almost never executes, but the strange return of zero size disappeared now. So, I think @JakobHøgenes can not rely upon the return of zero.

Comment: 0 means that a graceful disconnect is on the way. Read the documentation for the `Socket.Shutdown()` method.

Comment: @jgauffin yes, I am aware of documentation, and what I see seems to be an undocumented behavior. I can even show [the simple loop in which I suffer of a problem](http://pastebin.com/jH6kWnD9) — the return  of zero size appeared for me very often, and just after that happens, the loop continues, and a few cycles later usually do receive a new data. The behavior disappeared after I added the poll.

Comment: If you do think that it's just the return after the *poll* executes now — no, it isn't.

Comment: Aren't you using a non-blocking socket then?

Comment: I just checked, it is blocking; either way, even if it wouldn't, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w3xtz6a5(v=vs.110).aspx) says about it: *«If you are in non-blocking mode, and there is no data available in the in the protocol stack buffer, the Receive method will complete immediately and throw a SocketException.»©*

Comment: This answer is not correct. Remote close causes zero, but zero doesn't necessarily imply remote close. It will also return zero if the local application has shutdown the socket for input.

Comment: @EJP: Do you have a link to a credible source that says that? So I can update my answer with it? MSDN is a bit lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confused. The *Socket* is open until *you* close it. The *connection* is open until either end closes it. The *read side* of a connection can be closed by the sender shutting it down for output. So when reading a connection you will receive zero if the peer has either closed *his* socket or shut it down for output. At that point, *your socket* is still open, although you should now close it.

It will also return zero if the local application has shutdown the socket for input.